# ¿Como puedo pasarle argumentos a un comando en python?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

Este es el codigo , como podran ver es un codigo muy simple , pero lo que quiero hacer es que despues de abrir la cmd pasarle el argumento 'cd c:' , para posicionarme en la ruta c: una vez que abra la cmd , agradezco mucho la ayuda de cualquiera que me pueda explicar

aca esta el codigo

```py
import os

os.system('start cmd')
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto podría servir:

```python
import os

os.system("start cmd /k cd C:\\")
```

La opción `/k` de `cmd` permite pasar un comando para que sea ejecutado y luego continúa. [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) se puede consultar la documentación de esta opción y otras más.

Se deben usar dos `\` porque `\` es el carácter de escape. Si se usara uno solo Python entendería que se estaría escapando el caracter siguiente (`"`) y la cadena no estaría bien formada.

Comment: Guaao me ayudaste muchisimo gracias aprecio tu ayuda ....

Comment: @グラテロールErikku [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Existe otra forma que desarrolle con el modulo subprocess para ejecutar comandos externos de consola en python, el codigo quedo muy sencillo para mejor comprension de lo que intento hacer, aca el codigo :

````py
        #!/usr/bin/env python
        #_*_coding: utf-8 _*_
        #code by : Erick-Akejandro
    
        import subprocess
        try:
            arg = str(input("Ejecutar comando externo (SIN) : "))
            completed = subprocess.run(arg , shell=True)
            log = completed.returncode
        
            if log == 0 :
                print("Aca tu comando :")
            else log == 1 :
                print("Hubo un error interno :")
        except FileNotFoundError: 
            print("sorry hubo un error , no se encontro tu comando")
            print("sugerencias : No intentes correr un programa solo comandos")
        ```
````